# Bootstrap nav-justified not working in IE 8,9. They are stacking instead of aligning next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

I have some issue with the nav menu of my website against the IE (again). Here I am trying to use Twitter's bootstrap to set up a menu bar for my website. Each of these items are supposed to align next to each other, which works well for Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. On Internet Explorer, however, each of the menu item are stacked on top of each other, and one menu item does occupy the entire width of the container. I wonder why the 'nav-justified' is not working on IE..?

Here is the header section:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/master.css" />    
    <script src="lib/engine.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the menu elements:

```
<div width="100%" style="color:white;"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified menu_bar">
        <li><a href="#/knowing_us" item="active" data-toggle="pill" class="menu_text">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/new_projects" data-toggle="pill" class="menu_text">NEW PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/current_projects" data-toggle="pill" class="menu_text">CURRENT PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/previous_projects" data-toggle="pill" class="menu_text">PAST PROJECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/news_promotions" data-toggle="pill" class="menu_text">NEWS & PROMOTION</a></li>              
        <li><a href="#/contact_us" data-toggle="pill" class="menu_text">CONTACT US</a></li>                                                         
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css...

```
.menu_bar > li > a:hover,
.menu_bar > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #312f32;
    border: none;
    color: #ddd241;
}
.menu_text {
    font-family:'Cordia new'; 
    font-size:140%;
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #99979a; 
}
```

This is my first time developing a website, and now I see the painful of ppl creating website for the IE... :'(

Answer (score -1):

Making the `<li>` element float left in IE seems to fix it. You can add this to your HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.menu_bar > li {
  float: left;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: this isn't working for me :|... elements did float up but there width(1% for .nav-justified > li) is still an issue.